# Show that $\lim_{|P|\to 0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{W(t_{k+1})+W(t_k)}{2}\left[W(t_{k+1})-W(t_k)\right]=\frac{W^2(T)}{2}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have this problem which I am stuck in because it seems very obvious to me that the result is correct, but I don't know how $|P|\to 0$ can be used in the proof. Thanks a lot!

**QUESTION:**
Show that
$$\lim_{|P|\to 0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{W(t_{k+1})+W(t_k)}{2}\left[W(t_{k+1})-W(t_k)\right]=\frac{W^2(T)}{2}$$
where
$$P=\{0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=T\}$$
is a partition of $[0,T]$

**ATTEMPT:**

We have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{W(t_{k+1})+W(t_k)}{2}\left[W(t_{k+1})-W(t_k)\right]=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(W_{k+1}^2-W_k^2\right)$$

I know that
$$\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(W_{k+1}^2-W_k^2\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}\left(W^2(t_{k+1})-W^2(t_k)\right)\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(t_{k+1}-t_k\right)=\frac{1}{2}t_n=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}W^2(t_n)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}W^2(T)$$
But how does $|P|\to 0$ affect this? Would it be correct to leave it like this?

**COMMENT**

I have attached the picture of a similar problem which I could solve, but I don't know how to use a similar technique to prove it in this case.[image]

Comment: could you maybe add to your question, what P actually is - I am sure then you'll see how the limit affects the sum! I am not sure how you derived the last line, but as far as I know one uses telescope sums to get to your desired result

Comment: One other thing: you cannot just skip the limit part, since this is just the definition of the Stratonovich integral

Comment: Edited. But $P$ is the same thing in every book and online resources about stochastic processes I have found so I assumed it should be clear.

Comment: yes, it is actually well known. So now you see, that the size (you need to define and add this as well) of your partition $P$ goes to zero, when $n\to\infty$. Why do you think this $\frac{1}{2}t_n=\frac{1}{2}W^2(t_n)$ should actually be true?

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! It would be correct if we were taking the expected value, but wrong in the way I used it. I have edited the post to correct that and also added a photo of the previous exercise, but I am really struggling to use a similar technique to solve this problem.

Comment: on the picture you actually computed the Ito integral, now you want to compute the Stratonovich integral (which looks very similar), luckily the computation is in this case way easier

Comment: Sorry to ruin the party but, **for every partition P** the LHS is exactly $\frac12W_T^2$. No limit involved, no stochastic notion either, just the algebraic identity $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$...

Comment: @Did I will add your remark to the answer...you're right, this indeed holds for every partition, but since I thought it might be good idea to compute the Stratonovich integral along its definition, I had to include the limit of the partition...although one can easily drop the limit after using the binomial formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so we want to compute the Stratonovich $S$ integral, which is defined

$$
S:=\int_0^TW_t\circ dW_t:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2}(W_{t_{i+1}}+W_{t_{i}})(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})
$$
while we have a partition $P$ of $[0,T]$ with stepsize $h=T/n$, so 
$$
t_0=0,t_1=h,\dots,t_k=kh,\dots,t_n=T
$$
so as $n\to\infty$ we have $|P|\to 0$.

Now let's compute $S$

[**EDIT**: as pointed out by Did in the comments, the equality which we will show holds for every partition of $[0,T]$ since we will essentially make only use of the binomial formula $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ and the two fixed points of the partition $\{t_0=0,t_n=T\}$ and their relation to the Brownian motion.

So no limiting ever happens, although we should keep in mind, that the limiting process remains in general a part of the definition of the corresponding Stratonovich integral]

$$
S:=\int_0^TW_t\circ dW_t:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2}(W_{t_{i+1}}+W_{t_{i}})(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2}(W_{t_{i+1}}^2-W_{t_{i}}^2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2}(W_{t_{n}}^2-W_{t_{0}}^2)=\frac{1}{2}(W_{T}^2-W_{0}^2)=\frac{1}{2}W_T
$$
while we used the telescope sum and the fact that by definition we have $W_0=0$ and $W_{t_{n}}=W_T$.

bests

Comment: This answer could be greatly enhanced by the simple remark that **no limit is involved**, only algebra, see my comment to the question.

Comment: @Did (it) I just greatly enhanced the answer...is there actually any reason whatsoever why you find this remarkable, I never really worked with the Stratonovich Integral...so please feel free to add whatever thoughts you might have to the answer, I am sure one could say a lot more

Comment: I do not think I said I found this *remarkable*.

Comment: @Did you didn't, I meant it literally, remarkable in the sense of worth a remark, as I said, feel free to add, I certainly wouldn't mind